# How to Create and use a sequence to handle generating and populating in PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

How to Create and use a sequence to handle generating and populating the order ID. The first number issued by this sequence should be 11080, and no caching should be used. Use a record variable to handle the data to be added. Row data contains below.
Customerid: a valid customer id from the customer table
employeeid: a valid employee id from the employees table
territoryid: a valid territory id from the territories table
Orderdate: today's date

```
CREATE SEQUENCE ORDERID_SEQ
    INCREMENT BY 1
    START WITH 11080
    MINVALUE 11080
    MAXVALUE 20000
    CYCLE
```

I tried the above code but I have no idea to answer furthermore.

Comment: An on insert trigger that populates the primary key value with sequence values from your sequence should work.

Answer (score 2):

During an INSERT you need to reference the sequence

INSERT INTO orders
VALUES
(ORDERID_SEQ.nextval.... rest of VALUES